# Getting library "libjsc.so" not found after upgrading React Native to 0.60-RC2

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, androidx

I have updated React Native to 0.60-RC2, migrated to AndroidX using the Android Studio refractor and used the jetifier mentioned here: https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/issues/129

After doing this, I get the error `library "libjsc.so" not found` when running `react-native run-android`. i get the same error when running a release APK.

The stacktrace is:

```
06-24 15:55:01.823  8579  8656 E SoLoader: Error when loading lib: dlopen failed: library "libjsc.so" not found lib hash: 83f1717c1dc187d9f252a9f1fc66d430 search path is /data/app/com.jtv.testapp-4hvCKbqEmbyyOPykuQhm4Q==/lib/arm
06-24 15:55:01.823  8579  8656 E SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so caused by: dlopen failed: library "libjsc.so" not found
06-24 15:55:01.825  8579  8656 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
06-24 15:55:01.825  8579  8656 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.jtv.testapp, PID: 8579
06-24 15:55:01.825  8579  8656 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so caused by: dlopen failed: library "libjsc.so" not found
06-24 15:55:01.825  8579  8656 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:738)
06-24 15:55:01.825  8579  8656 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:591)
06-24 15:55:01.825  8579  8656 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:529)
06-24 15:55:01.825  8579  8656 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:484)
06-24 15:55:01.825  8579  8656 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor.<clinit>(JSCExecutor.java:19)
06-24 15:55:01.825  8579  8656 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutorFactory.create(JSCExecutorFactory.java:29)
06-24 15:55:01.825  8579  8656 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:949)
06-24 15:55:01.825  8579  8656 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

My `package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "TestApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^3.3.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^1.2.3",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^1.0.4",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.4.0",
    "native-base": "^2.10.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "qs": "^6.6.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "^0.60.0-rc.2",
    "react-native-appsee": "^2.6.21",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.24.3",
    "react-native-dialog": "^5.5.0",
    "react-native-draggable-flatlist": "^1.1.7",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-email": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^5.1.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.12",
    "react-native-iap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.0",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-kochava-tracker": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.3",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-orientation": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.7.5",
    "react-native-super-grid": "^2.4.4",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-underline-tabbar": "^1.3.6",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
    "react-native-video": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-webview": "^5.12.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
    "react-navigation-backhandler": "^1.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "eslint": "^5.15.3",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.5.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "react-devtools-core": "^3.6.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.16"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

My `build.gradle` is:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
        entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

project.ext.vectoricons = [
    iconFontNames: [ 'MaterialIcons.ttf', 'FontAwesome.ttf', 'MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf' ]
]
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jtv.testapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 29
        versionName "0.0.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 29
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "x86_64","armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        packagingOptions {
            pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
            pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
            exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libimagepipeline.so"
            exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/librealm-jni.so"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-webview')
    implementation project(':react-native-jtv-comic-reader')
    //implementation project(':@react-native-community_slider')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_blur')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_async-storage')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_netinfo')
    implementation project(':react-native-appsee')
//    implementation project(':react-native-tune-sdk')
    implementation project(':react-native-iap')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-video')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-orientation')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-kochava-tracker')
//    implementation project(':react-native-flurry-analytics')
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
//    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    implementation project(':react-native-fast-image')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.13.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.13.0'
    implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3:interactivemedia:3.11.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.36.1'
    implementation 'com.swrve.sdk.android:swrve-firebase:6.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:17.0.0'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What is the `libjsc.so` file and how do I solve this error?

Comment: open  gradle.properties => add Android.useDeprecatedNdk=true

Comment: It is already there. I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add below in your app/build.gradle

// On **top** of the **file**

```
def useIntlJsc = false
```

//inside **dependencies**

```
 if (useIntlJsc) {
        implementation 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'
    } else {
        implementation 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
    }
```

Comment: I actually deleted the old project, created a new one from `react-native init` and copied my code onto the new project and it worked. So I can't test this fix.

If you are 100% sure this works, then I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: had same problem yesterday, this is how I fixed. With new project you will get above setup as default. You can validate in your generated app/build.gradle

Comment: This gets rid of `libjsc.so` error but now I'm getting `libgnustl_shared.so` not found on a fresh new RN 0.60 RC2 project.

Comment: This solution does not work. I get
/com.simplewebview E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so caused by: dlopen failed: library "libgnustl_shared.so" not found
/com.simplewebview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
    Process: com.simplewebview, PID: 26654
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so caused by: dlopen failed: library "libgnustl_shared.so" not found

Comment: Can anyone sharing the working build.gradle and the package.json?

Comment: Getting the same issue with `libgnustl_shared.so`.  Does anyone have a solution and a reasonable explanation as to why it's not in the react-native docs?

Comment: Perfect. Solved my issue.

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue too. I needed to update the `jscFlavor` variable inside the build.gradle file from this:

```
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
```

To this:

```
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'
```

Cheers.

Comment: This one actually saved me. Thank you a lot. I do use i18n in my app.

Answer (score 6):

What solved for me was change build.gradle updating `packagingOptions` to:

```
  packagingOptions {
       pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/x86/libjsc.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so'
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any of that in my build.gradle.  Is this part of a fresh setup of react-native? https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.61.5&to=0.63.0

Comment: @Chris I don't think so. But it's something that you are asked to add if you installed react-native-pdf: https://github.com/wonday/react-native-pdf/#android-installation - it might be that the paths are incorrect / doesn't include JSC for a given architecture, so when you run it on that particular phone/architecture, it's a valid app... just not for that phone, so it crashes because it's missing the JSC (javascript engine)

Answer (score 6):

I encountered a slight variation of this bug, where I had added a third buildType to my gradle config, 'releaseStaging'

The fix in this instance was to add the following line to dependencies in app/build.gradle

`releaseStagingImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")`

Comment: Saved me!, I was using a custom staging variant and hermes didn't work, Thanks!

Comment: Same here. Hermes must be enabled for each buildType where it is needed. This change solved it for me

Answer (score 1):

Okay ! In the recent versions of react native till today this issue is occurring and is being reported in the crashlytics that you integrate within the app or you can see it in the logs.

*`This issue only comes when you have Hermes engine enabled.`*

Here is my fix for this I was facing this issue, in my case Hermes was needed so, I managed to fix this `"libjsc.so" not found` by installing the `jsc-android` package from `npm`. Here is the [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsc-android).

**`Please NOTE`** : Refer to the docs of this package for proper installation as per your react native version

clean gradle and re run the entire app this issue will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, This error was related with react-native-screen and adding following
 following two lines to dependencies section in android/app/build.gradle fixed the issue for me

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02'
```

Source:[Check out this Github answer](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6267#issuecomment-528883756)

Comment: How is that related to the original question??