# react native app force close on launch without error after upgrading from 0.58.x to 0.67.1

Tags: android, react-native

First of all, the reason why I upgrading my project from RN 0.58.x to 0.67.1 is because yesterday I suddenly got this error without reason:

> "Unexpected identifier '_classCallCheck'.import call expects exactly
> one argument"

But after this upgrade, I got another problem when I try to run the app. It keep crashing when the application is open without any red screen error. so, I try to run `adb logcat` and got this error log:

```
01-27 10:53:12.727  1517  5012 I MediaProvider: Invalidating LocalCallingIdentity cache for package com.kidrn. Reason: op android:read_external_storage
01-27 10:53:12.728  1517  5012 I MediaProvider: Invalidating LocalCallingIdentity cache for package com.kidrn. Reason: op android:read_external_storage
01-27 10:53:12.728  1517  5012 I MediaProvider: Invalidating LocalCallingIdentity cache for package com.kidrn. Reason: op android:read_external_storage
01-27 10:53:12.728  1517  5012 I MediaProvider: Invalidating LocalCallingIdentity cache for package com.kidrn. Reason: op android:read_external_storage
01-27 10:53:12.746   536   604 V BackupManagerService: [UserID:0] restoreAtInstall pkg=com.kidrn token=1 restoreSet=0
01-27 10:53:12.775  1517  1517 I MediaProvider: Invalidating LocalCallingIdentity cache for package com.kidrn. Reason: package android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
01-27 10:53:12.780  2488  2488 I GsaVoiceInteractionSrv: O received Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.kidrn flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
01-27 10:53:12.784   536  2363 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.kidrn flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstalledReceiver
01-27 10:53:12.786   536   583 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.kidrn flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.games.chimera.GamesSystemBroadcastReceiverProxy
01-27 10:53:12.786   536   583 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.kidrn flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.gass.chimera.PackageChangeBroadcastReceiver

01-27 10:53:12.786   536   583 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.kidrn flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
01-27 10:53:12.786   536   583 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.kidrn flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.googlequicksearchbox.GelStubAppWatcher

01-27 10:53:12.975   536   601 E VerityUtils: Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~mjBGPpGCHDpAD72r_s1hnA==/com.kidrn-SDMUbkOOrQInHEMk-VIhrQ==/base.apk
01-27 10:53:12.996  1127  5553 W GCM     : Unexpected forwarded intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.kidrn flg=0x4000010 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.chimera.PersistentIntentOperationService (has extras) }
01-27 10:53:13.007  1003  1003 D ImsResolver: maybeAddedImsService, packageName: com.kidrn
01-27 10:53:13.024  1127  5558 W GCM     : Unexpected forwarded intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.kidrn flg=0x4000010 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.chimera.PersistentIntentOperationService (has extras) }
01-27 10:53:14.070   536   924 I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.kidrn/.MainActivity} from uid 2000
01-27 10:53:14.124   536   924 V SplashScreenExceptionList: SplashScreen checking exception for package com.kidrn (target sdk:27) -> false
01-27 10:53:14.165   786   856 D StartingSurfaceDrawer: addSplashScreen com.kidrn theme=7f0d0007 task=13 suggestType=3
01-27 10:53:14.207   536   584 I ActivityManager: Start proc 5569:com.kidrn/u0a147 for pre-top-activity {com.kidrn/com.kidrn.MainActivity}
01-27 10:53:14.234  5569  5569 I com.kidrn: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-27 10:53:14.736  5569  5569 V GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE Developer option for 'com.kidrn' set to: 'default'
01-27 10:53:14.753  5569  5569 D SoLoader: adding application source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~mjBGPpGCHDpAD72r_s1hnA==/com.kidrn-SDMUbkOOrQInHEMk-VIhrQ==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
01-27 10:53:14.753  5569  5569 D SoLoader: adding backup source from : com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/user/0/com.kidrn/lib-main flags = 1]
01-27 10:53:14.753  5569  5569 D SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~mjBGPpGCHDpAD72r_s1hnA==/com.kidrn-SDMUbkOOrQInHEMk-VIhrQ==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
01-27 10:53:14.753  5569  5569 D SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/user/0/com.kidrn/lib-main flags = 1]
01-27 10:53:14.755  5569  5569 V fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.kidrn/lib-main
01-27 10:53:14.815  5569  5569 V fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.kidrn/lib-main (from syncer thread)
01-27 10:53:14.815  5569  5569 V fb-UnpackingSoSource: not releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.kidrn/lib-main (syncer thread started)
01-27 10:53:14.847  5569  5569 D SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/user/0/com.kidrn/lib-main
01-27 10:53:14.847  5569  5569 D SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so found on /data/app/~~mjBGPpGCHDpAD72r_s1hnA==/com.kidrn-SDMUbkOOrQInHEMk-VIhrQ==/lib/arm64
01-27 10:53:14.847  5569  5569 W System.err: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libjsc.so" not found: needed by /data/app/~~mjBGPpGCHDpAD72r_s1hnA==/com.kidrn-SDMUbkOOrQInHEMk-VIhrQ==/lib/arm64/libjscexecutor.so in namespace classloader-namespace
01-27 10:53:14.848  5569  5569 E SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so caused by: dlopen failed: library "libjsc.so" not found: needed by /data/app/~~mjBGPpGCHDpAD72r_s1hnA==/com.kidrn-SDMUbkOOrQInHEMk-VIhrQ==/lib/arm64/libjscexecutor.so in namespace classloader-namespace result: 0
01-27 10:53:14.849  5569  5569 D SoLoader: libhermes.so not found on /data/user/0/com.kidrn/lib-main
01-27 10:53:14.849  5569  5569 D SoLoader: libhermes.so not found on /data/app/~~mjBGPpGCHDpAD72r_s1hnA==/com.kidrn-SDMUbkOOrQInHEMk-VIhrQ==/lib/arm64
01-27 10:53:14.850  5569  5569 E SoLoader:  SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/user/0/com.kidrn/lib-main flags = 1]
01-27 10:53:14.850  5569  5569 E SoLoader:  SoSource 1: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~mjBGPpGCHDpAD72r_s1hnA==/com.kidrn-SDMUbkOOrQInHEMk-VIhrQ==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
01-27 10:53:14.850  5569  5569 E SoLoader:  Native lib dir: /data/app/~~mjBGPpGCHDpAD72r_s1hnA==/com.kidrn-SDMUbkOOrQInHEMk-VIhrQ==/lib/arm64
01-27 10:53:14.850  5569  5569 W System.err:    SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/user/0/com.kidrn/lib-main flags = 1]
01-27 10:53:14.850  5569  5569 W System.err:    SoSource 1: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~mjBGPpGCHDpAD72r_s1hnA==/com.kidrn-SDMUbkOOrQInHEMk-VIhrQ==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
01-27 10:53:14.850  5569  5569 W System.err:    Native lib dir: /data/app/~~mjBGPpGCHDpAD72r_s1hnA==/com.kidrn-SDMUbkOOrQInHEMk-VIhrQ==/lib/arm64
01-27 10:53:14.851  5569  5569 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.kidrn, PID: 5569
01-27 10:53:14.851  5569  5569 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so caused by: dlopen failed: library "libjsc.so" not found: needed by /data/app/~~mjBGPpGCHDpAD72r_s1hnA==/com.kidrn-SDMUbkOOrQInHEMk-VIhrQ==/lib/arm64/libjscexecutor.so in namespace classloader-namespace result: 0
01-27 10:53:14.851  5569  5569 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libjsc.so" not found: needed by /data/app/~~mjBGPpGCHDpAD72r_s1hnA==/com.kidrn-SDMUbkOOrQInHEMk-VIhrQ==/lib/arm64/libjscexecutor.so in namespace classloader-namespace
01-27 10:53:14.854   536   718 W ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.kidrn/.MainActivity
01-27 10:53:14.907   536  2364 I ActivityManager: Process com.kidrn (pid 5569) has died: prcp TOP 
01-27 10:53:14.913   536  2364 W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object '83cbc90 Splash Screen com.kidrn (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
01-27 10:53:15.356   536   575 W ActivityTaskManager: Activity top resumed state loss timeout for ActivityRecord{7302bdb u0 com.kidrn/.MainActivity t-1 f}}
```

Any idea what is the root of the problem after or before upgrading? Thank you!

Comment: `dlopen failed: library "libjsc.so" not found` and similar seem interesting. Any internet search results? (And yes, there is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56734877)

Comment: @user2864740 oh okay, I'll try to check it out. thank you!

Comment: @user2864740 The force close problem is solved. unfortunately, the main problem is still occured even after upgrading version. But I think that's just different topic. Thank you!